# Installing MongoDB and PHP Driver on bluehost

Tags: linux, mongodb, bluehost

I need to install mongdb on a real webserver ,

I tried the link here : http://tchvan.wordpress.com/mongodbandphponbluehost/

and it did not work I receive error

```
mongo shell  Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
```

Can any one guide me to the steps of doing this in the right way. I have been searching for more than 2 hours now with no result.

Comment: Is 'mongodb' running?  What happens when you run the command 'ps -ef | grep mongod' on your webserver machine?

Comment: It tell me it's running :
'abojeeco 14856 14111  0 02:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mongo'. May be the problem is in the php driver ??

Comment: That tells you it is **NOT** runnning.  That's just your grep command.  What command did you use to try to start 'mongod'.